# Load key "/c/Users/xxxx/.ssh/id_rsa.pub": invalid format

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I use windows10 and when i tried to use git push, it occured an error:

```
Load key "/c/Users/Tnxts/.ssh/id_rsa.pub": invalid format
git@20.205.243.166: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I find a solution is

```
eval `ssh-agent -s` 
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

I tried this and find it works, but if i close the shell window or open another shell window it doesn't work again. If i want use VScode to git push, it still doesn't work.

The following is my ssh config:

```
Host github.com
                  HostName 20.205.243.166
                  User git
                  PreferredAuthentications publickey
                  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

ERROR:
[image: Screenshot of an error message]

Comment: The `IdentifyFile` (and the key added to the aah agent with `ssh-add`) must be the file containing the private key, not the public key. In your case, this is likely `~/.ssh/id_rsa` (without the `.pub`).

Comment: It works!!Thanks!!
Now my config just contains:
Host github.com
    HostName 20.205.243.166
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Comment: For what it's worth, you sometimes (but not always) *can* point the IdentityFile line to the `.pub` file. This mostly seems to correlate with use of the ssh agent: the agent provides the private key for each public key, and the IdentityFile line tells ssh which one of the key-pairs to use. But pointing ssh to the private-key file works even if you're not using the agent.